# EF Core 7 One-To-Many relationship back to same table with intermediate table

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, one-to-many, ef-core-7.0

Using this model:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Person> Children { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
    public virtual List<Person> Parents { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
    public virtual List<Person> Spouses { get;  set; } = new List<Person>();
}
```

I've built this intermediate table

```
public class Marriage
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public int SpouseId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Spouse { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime MarriageDate { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DivorceDate { get; set; }
}
```

I've defined the relationship between Parents and Children as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Children)
    .WithMany(p => p.Parents)
    .UsingEntity<PersonPerson>(
        s => s.HasOne(prop => prop.Parent).WithMany().HasForeignKey(prop => prop.ChildrenId),
        s => s.HasOne(prop => prop.Child).WithMany().HasForeignKey(prop => prop.ParentId),
        pp =>
        {
            pp.HasKey(prop => new { prop.ParentId, prop.ChildrenId });
        }
    );
```

I can't figure out how to build the relationship between Person and Spouses using the intermediate table.

This is what I have tried:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasOne(p => p)
    .WithMany(p => p.Spouses)
    .UsingEntity<Marriage>(
        m => m.HasOne(prop => prop.Person)
              .WithMany(Prop.Spouse)
              .HasForeignKey(prop => prop.SpouseId),
        m =>
        {
            m.HasKey(prop => new { prop.PersonId, prop.SpouseId });
        }
    );
```

I get the error 'ReferenceCollectionBuilder<Person,Person>' does not contain a definition for 'UsingEntity'

Comment: It should be very similar to the parent-children relationship you already have. What issues do you have configuring this relationship using Marriage instead of PersonPerson?

Comment: The Parent to Child Relationship is many to many, so I have a List of Parents and a list of Children. Then in model builder i reference the Parents List and the Children's List. For the one-to-many relationship for Spouses I have a List of Spouses in the Person model but no way of referring to "self" when setting up the entity model.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this really is a many-to-many relationship, not a one-to-many. This fix is to add a second Spouses list to the Person model. The Person model now looks like this:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Person> Children { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
    public virtual List<Person> Parents { get; set; } = new List<Person>();
    public virtual List<Person> Spouses { get;  set; } = new List<Person>();
}
```

And the Fluent API looks like this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
     .HasMany(p => p.Spouses)
     .WithMany(p => p.SpousesFrom)
     .UsingEntity<Marriage>(
         s => s.HasOne(prop => prop.Person).WithMany().HasForeignKey(prop => prop.SpouseId),
         s => s.HasOne(prop => prop.Spouse).WithMany().HasForeignKey(prop => prop.PersonId),
         pp =>
         {
             pp.HasKey(prop => new { prop.PersonId, prop.SpouseId });
         }
     );
```

Then in the controller you save them like this:

```
if (!Person.Spouses.Contains(spouse))
   {
       Person.Spouses.Add(spouse);
       spouse.IsSelected = false;
       spouseAdded = true;
   }
if (!spouse.Spouses.Contains(Person))
   {
       spouse.Spouses.Add(Person);
   }
```